# Efficient way to map my Ip address with subnet and subnet mask in java

Tags: java, ip, subnet

I am having set of subnet and subnet masks in a db table with a APN. I want retrieve the mapping APN.

`10.0.0.0, 255.0.0.0, broadband`

`172.28.0.0, 255.255.0.0, internet`

`20.12.0.0, 255.255.0.0, video`

How can I map my ip with a given set of subnet and subnet mask in Java

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to find out to what APN your IP corresponds, then you need to apply each subnet mask to the IP address, and then lookup the subnet and retrieve the APN.

I don't understand if you want to do this on the DB, on Java, or some form of collaboration between both.

Comment: Want to do in java code level. Basically need the java code to apply each subnet mask to the IP address and get the mapping APN from the retrieved list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a non unique key Map (TreeMap) that holds your ipaddress as the key, the values of the TreeMap can be another TreeMap with the subnet being the key and the APN as the value.

I hope this is what you were asking.